# Checking pids under all users and re-launching the processes after reboot

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

Is there a way to check all pids of all users under `/home` directory, and to run these processes again after a reboot or shutdown?

For example, if `user1` was running a psybnc and `user2` was running an eggdrop, I wish to re-run these processes, after a reboot, from a single shell command or script.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you might want to do this?  There are several ways to start scripts at bootup, but the best approach depends...

Comment: i have a dedicated server and i have allowed psybnc and eggdrop on it, i have more than 400 users. i accidently got it rebooted, now i want to start all these processes.

Comment: i tried writing a shell script but this one just stucks after su'ing in to first user .. the script is #!/bin/bash

d=$(gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd)
for i in $d
 do
echo "$i"
su "$i"
cd ~/psybnc
./psybnc
exit
done

Comment: ok fixed the script its working fine now .. #!/bin/bash

d=$(gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd)
for i in $d
 do
su $i -c 'cd ~/psybnc;./psybnc;exit'
done

Comment: Hi Daud, if you have the answer, please add it as an answer and accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash 
d=$(gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd) 
for i in $d 
do 
su $i -c 'cd ~/psybnc;./psybnc;exit' 
done
```